# Deploying AWS Glue Job via AWS CloudFormation: Failed to properly render job config field for: language

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I'm using AWS CloudFormation templates to deploy an AWS Glue Job as per below:

```
...
"GluePythonScriptRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole"
        ]
      }
    },
    "GluePythonScriptJob": {
      "Type": "AWS::Glue::Job",
      "DependsOn": "GluePythonScriptRole",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": {
          "Fn::Sub": "add-partition-projection-to-all-tables-${UniqueID}"
        },
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "GluePythonScriptRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "ExecutionProperty": {
          "MaxConcurrentRuns": 1
        },
        "Command": {
          "Name": "pythonshell",
          "ScriptLocation": "s3://xyz/add-partition-projection-to-all-tables.py"
        },
        "DefaultArguments": {
          "--databasename": {
            "Fn::Sub": "dbparquet${UniqueID}"
          }
        },
        "MaxRetries": 0,
        "Timeout": 2880
      }
    },
...
```

I've verified that the Glue Job and related Python script works as intended when setting it up manually. But when my Glue Job is created via the CFT I get error messages as below:

```
Failed to properly render job config field for: language. Please verify its value.
```

See also below screenshot:
[image]

It seems like my CFT may be missing something?

Comment: Can you try adding that following key value pairs to the "DefaultArguments" property: '--job-language': 'python'. According to the docs this is the default value but because for some reason It can not be render this might resolve the issue. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html#:~:text=bookmark%2Denable%27-,%2D%2Djob%2Dlanguage,If%20this%20parameter%20is%20not%20present%2C%20the%20default%20is%20python.,-%2D%2Dpython%2Dmodules%2Dinstaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up updating the CFT as follows to get it working, I think adding the Python version explicitly was required:

```
"GluePythonScriptJob": {
      "Type": "AWS::Glue::Job",
      "DependsOn": "GluePythonScriptRole",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": {
          "Fn::Sub": "add-partition-projection-to-all-tables-${UniqueID}"
        },
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "GluePythonScriptRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "ExecutionProperty": {
          "MaxConcurrentRuns": 1
        },
        "Command": {
          "Name": "pythonshell",
          "PythonVersion": "3.9",
          "ScriptLocation": "s3://xyz/add-partition-projection-to-all-tables.py"
        },
        "DefaultArguments": {
          "--databasename": {
            "Fn::Sub": "dbparquet${UniqueID}"
          },
          "--job-language": "python",
          "--additional-python-modules": "boto3"
        },
        "MaxRetries": 0,
        "Timeout": 2880
      }
    }
```